# Hide / Add / Replace dock icons on home screen

Tags: applications, settings, home-screen, samsung-galaxy-y

I have Samsung galaxy Y and I do have 2 questions about dock settings on home screen.

1. Is it possible to Hide / Modify dock on home screen?
2. Is it possible to make it toggle on touch the home screen?

Answer (score 1):

This functionality isn't available as standard in your default launcher, but the launcher is replaceable.  There are lots of alternatives out there, some require a minimum OS version.  Unless you've rooted your phone it looks like the maximum OS version you can be on is v2.3.5 (Source: http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_y_s5360-4117.php).  So this rules out the newer breed of launchers which are based on the Android 4.x launcher.  BUT there are still a load of good launchers which will be compatible with your phone and will provide the functionality that you're looking for.  Have a look at:

- [Go Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gau.go.launcherex)
- [ADW Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.adw.launcher)

Answer (score 0):

My first suggestion is to look into replacing your launcher. You can find several Home Launcher replacements in [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store) Market.

My current favorite is the [Holo Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mobint.hololauncher).

**[Alternatively](http://howto.cnet.com/8301-11310_39-57410133-285/how-to-change-the-docked-icons-on-samsung-touchwiz/)**

Comment: Hi designerWhoCodes, sorry I don't know your actual name :).
I tried alternate way you suggested as I don't want to use application if its possible by default settings. But I couldn't find any dock settings under settings from menu.

Comment: I provided clearer instructions via a new link. My name is Mark. I used the google authenticate and it created my user name from my blog.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Holo launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mobint.hololauncher): Really an awesome launcher, you will get an ICS look and you can hide Icons in the drawer; you can also add icons in the dock session. Use it and I bet you gonna really like the holo launcher.